# can't centre header, main body and footer in my website

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website, but the content is covering the entire width of my computer screen. if I try to edit the width% of the elements, some elements are left-aligned and some are center-aligned. I want to decrease the width of the elements by around 50%, so it's not covering the screen completely (horizontally). any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: url('https://lifted.crd.co/assets/images/gallery01/a307cfec.png?v=a0ae4590');
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@font-face {
  src: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/uougf9v63jmphoj/Jojoba.otf);
  font-family: jojoba;
}

div {
  font-family: jojoba;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Style the header */

header {
  background-color: #666;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgb(240, 242, 240, 1) 10%, rgba(217, 219, 218, 1) 43%, rgb(240, 242, 240, 1) 75%);
}


/* Create two columns/boxes that floats next to each other */

nav {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  /* only for demonstration, should be removed */
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* Style the list inside the menu */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

article {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 300px;
  /* only for demonstration, should be removed */
  overflow-y: auto;
  direction: ltr;
  scrollbar-color: #d4aa70 #e4e4e4;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

section::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Style the footer */

footer {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: rgb(219, 219, 219);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgb(240, 242, 240, 1) 10%, rgba(217, 219, 218, 1) 43%, rgb(240, 242, 240, 1) 75%);
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns/boxes stack on top of each other instead of next to each other, on small screens */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  nav,
  article {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<title>CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <div>

    <header>

    </header>

    <section>
      <nav>
        <img src="https://tomomi.neocities.org/doll/silentangel20.gif">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <article>
        <h2> yatori <img src="https://barbara.crd.co/assets/images/gallery07/fd56c474.gif?v=078d66a6"> </h2>

        lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </article>
    </section>

    <footer>

    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just set `section { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: _"where should i put it?"_ I didn't quite understand

Comment: @KunalTanwar i figured out where to put it and it fixed the body of the layout, but the header and footer are still covering the entire width of the website

Comment: apply the same on them too